# How to create new svg rect without overriding the previous one

Tags: javascript, svg

When I click somewhere in the svg, then a svg rect is created. That's working fine. But if I click somewhere again, then the previous created svg rect is overwritten.

Expected behavior: Every click should create a new svg rect without overwriting the previous rect.

Do you have any suggestions to realize the expected behavior?

```
    window.onload = setup;

    const svgcanvas = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    const path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");

    function setup() {
        svgcanvas.setAttribute("width", 600);
        svgcanvas.setAttribute("height", 600);
        svgcanvas.setAttribute("id", "column");
        svgcanvas.setAttribute("style", "background-color: grey;");
        svgcanvas.setAttribute("onclick", "handleClick()");

        document.body.appendChild(svgcanvas);

    }

    let y = 0;
    const rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
    let myTarget = 500;

    const handleClick = () => {
        rect.setAttribute("width", 100);
        rect.setAttribute("height", 100);
        rect.setAttribute("x", 100);
        rect.setAttribute("y", -50);
        rect.setAttribute("style", "fill: pink;");
        svgcanvas.appendChild(rect);
        y = y + 100;
        myTarget = myTarget -100;

        intervalId = setInterval(moveMyRect, 10);
    };

    const moveMyRect = () => {
        let rectCurrentYPosition = parseInt(rect.getAttribute("y"));
        if (rectCurrentYPosition === myTarget) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }

        rectCurrentYPosition = rectCurrentYPosition + 1;

        rect.setAttribute("y", rectCurrentYPosition);
    };
```

Comment: You will need to share your code in the form of a minimal, concrete and verifiable example. With no code shared whatsoever, it is impossible for us to point out where it could've gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have just solve it. How? Just pass the rect to the moveMyRect function. Here is the code that I have changes. I hope that helps someone.

```
    let y = 0;

    let myTarget = 500;

    const handleClick = () => {
        const rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
        rect.setAttribute("width", 100);
        rect.setAttribute("height", 100);
        rect.setAttribute("x", 100);
        rect.setAttribute("y", -50);
        rect.setAttribute("style", "fill: pink;");
        svgcanvas.appendChild(rect);
        y = y + 100;
        myTarget = myTarget -100;

        intervalId = setInterval(moveMyRect, 10, rect);
    };

    const moveMyRect = (theRect) => {
        let discCurrentYPosition = parseInt(theRect.getAttribute("y"));
        if (discCurrentYPosition === myTarget) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }

        discCurrentYPosition = discCurrentYPosition + 1;

        theRect.setAttribute("y", discCurrentYPosition);
    };
```